# Maven project won't write to file in JAR

Tags: java, maven

I write a method to write to a file. It works when running the program in the IDE but not when it's a JAR file, because apparently JARs are ZIPs.
How do I get around this and write to the file in a JAR?

The code below has a method for writing content to the file and another method to read the content. The reading works but writing does not.

The contents written to the file will be read and printed. the test2() method is simply to show if the test() method worked.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main mainTest = new Main();
        mainTest.test("hello world");
        System.out.println(mainTest.test2());
    }

    private void test(String text) {
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.txt")).getPath());

        try (
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)
        ) {
            bufferedWriter.write(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private String test2() {
        try (
                InputStream file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)
        ) {
            String line = "";

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
            }

            return line;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Files should be external to the application and configured via preferences, env or CLI vars, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to a file inside the JAR.

Sorry.

Write to some other directory, like a temp dir.